# Windows 10 is not showing after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I successfully installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad E430 laptop. Now I am facing problem that Windows 10 (which was already installed on my machine) is not showing in grub. I already tried to fix grub, but it did not succeed.

I installed Ubuntu on separate drive.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 reached end of life on 2016-02-04 and isn't supported any more. Please use a supported version of Ubuntu, like 14.04 or 15.10.

Comment: Hi Florian, I am also facing same problem with 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

"Well , we need to forget something in order to get something..."

1. restart
2. press f12 ( go to the boot menu)
3. select windows

It's always better to perform a backup of your files

Comment: I think I already done these steps, but it not works...

In simple words my problem is that grub is not showing windows 10 after I install ubuntu.